# How to group SQL DataRow results by Name depending on condition

Tags: powershell

I get results from a SQL Table with this command:

`$GetData = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ConnectionString $Connection -Query $GetQuery`

One single result looks like this (there are about 500 of these results):

```
ID                  : 1584
ObjId               : 
ARTIKEL_NR          : 0
ArtBeschrieb1_3     : 
KLASSE              : TbXAusführungen
SMB1                : Produkt
SMW1                : TbA
SMN1                : 
SMB2                : Ausführung
SMW2                : 2M-Zarge Front
SMN2                : 
SMB3                : Boxtypen
SMW3                : B;C-M;D-M
SMN3                : 
SMB4                : SortKZ
SMW4                : 
SMN4                : 2.000000
SMB5                : 
SMW5                : 
SMN5                : 
SMB6                : 
SMW6                : 
SMN6                : 
SMB7                : 
SMW7                : 
SMN7                : 
SMB8                : 
SMW8                : 
SMN8                : 
SMB9                : 
SMW9                : 
SMN9                : 
SMB10               : 
SMW10               : 
SMN10               : 
SMB11               : 
SMW11               : 
SMN11               : 
SMB12               : 
SMW12               : 
SMN12               : 
SMB13               : 
SMW13               : 
SMN13               : 
SMB14               : 
SMW14               : 
SMN14               : 
SMB15               : 
SMW15               : 
SMN15               : 
SMB16               : 
SMW16               : 
SMN16               : 
SMB17               : 
SMW17               : 
SMN17               : 
SMB18               : 
SMW18               : 
SMN18               : 
SMB19               : 
SMW19               : 
SMN19               : 
SMB20               : 
SMW20               : 
SMN20               : 
SMB21               : 
SMW21               : 
SMN21               : 
SMB22               : 
SMW22               : 
SMN22               : 
SMB23               : 
SMW23               : 
SMN23               : 
SMB24               : 
SMW24               : 
SMN24               : 
SMB25               : 
SMW25               : 
SMN25               : 
SMB26               : 
SMW26               : 
SMN26               : 
SMB27               : 
SMW27               : 
SMN27               : 
SMB28               : 
SMW28               : 
SMN28               : 
SMB29               : 
SMW29               : 
SMN29               : 
SMB30               : 
SMW30               : 
SMN30               : 
DividendPreisEinhet : 0
SMB31               : 
SMW31               : 
SMN31               : 
ArtBeschrieb1_2FR   : 
SMB32               : 
SMW32               : 
SMN32               : 
OOPreisklasse       : 
SMB33               : 
SMW33               : 
SMN33               : 
SMB34               : 
SMW34               : 
SMN34               : 
SMB35               : 
SMW35               : 
SMN35               : 
SMB36               : 
SMW36               : 
SMN36               : 
SMB37               : 
SMW37               : 
SMN37               : 
SMB38               : 
SMW38               : 
SMN38               : 
SMB39               : 
SMW39               : 
SMN39               : 
SMB40               : 
SMW40               : 
SMN40               :
```

As You can see there are always 3 `SM*` Properties with the same Number. I would like to group them. SMB* should become the Property Name and either SMW* or SMN* the PropertyValue, depending on which is NULL and which is not.

I think I can do the PropertyName / PropertyValue part on my own, but how can I group all corresponding SM* fields?

btw: The Fields that are not SM* fields are already OK, they should stay the way they are.

I know there is `$PSObject.Properties` but that does not seem to help me here?

```
PS Z:\Powershell-Scripts> $GetData.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was what I was actually looking for - sorry for not explaining it well enough

```
$GetData = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ConnectionString $ConnectionLogik -Query $GetQuery

$NewData = foreach ($dat in $GetData) 
{
    # Get rid of empty and useless Properties
    $NotArray = @("RowState","ItemArray","HasErrors")
    $Objects = $dat.Psobject.properties | 
      Where-Object {![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.Value) -and $_.Name -notin $NotArray} | 
      Select-Object Name, Value 

    # Create new Properties from pairs
    $SingleObject = [ordered]@{}
    foreach ($obj in $Objects) {
        if ($obj.Name -like 'SM*') {
            if ($obj.Name -like 'SMW*' -or $obj.Name -like 'SMN*') { Continue }
            $match = 'SM[NW]' + $obj.Name.Substring(3) + '$'
            $val = $Objects | Where-Object { $_.Name -match $match } | Select -Expand Value
            $SingleObject[$obj.Value] = $val
        } else {
            $SingleObject[$obj.Name] = $obj.Value
        }
    }
    [PSCustomObject]$SingleObject
}
```

This will leave me with output like this:

```
ID                  : 1584
ARTIKEL_NR          : 0
KLASSE              : TbXAusführungen
Produkt             : TbA
Ausführung          : 2M-Zarge Front
Boxtypen            : B;C-M;D-M
SortKZ              : 2.000000
DividendPreisEinhet : 0

ID                  : 443
ObjId               : 20854
ARTIKEL_NR          : 14.39007.00
ArtBeschrieb1_3     : Verpackung
KLASSE              : TbALeistungenAntaro
TextID              : Material.Verpackung
DividendPreisEinhet : 1

ID                  : 1528
ARTIKEL_NR          : 0
KLASSE              : TbXFrontbefestigung
ArtNoBlum           :
Bezeichnung         : keine
DividendPreisEinhet : 0
```

Which I was then able to export to CSV grouped by each KLASSE Property

`$NewData | Group-Object KLASSE | ForEach-Object { $_.Group | Export-Csv I:\TRANSFER\$($_.Name).csv -delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation }`

Answer (score 0):

Below code should do what you want:

```
$GetData = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ConnectionString $Connection -Query $GetQuery

$result = foreach ($item in $GetData) {
    # create an Ordered hash to collect the item data
    $newObject = [ordered]@{}
    # get all property names in order
    $propNames = ($item.PsObject.Properties).Name
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $propNames.Count; $i++) {
        $name = $propNames[$i]
        if ($name -notlike 'SM*') { 
            $newObject[$name] = $item.$name
        }
        else {
            $num = $name -replace '\D'
            $value = if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($item."SMW$num")) { $item."SMN$num" } else { $item."SMW$num" }
            $newObject["SMB$num"] = $value
            $i += 2
        }
    }
    [PsCustomObject]$newObject
}

# output on console
$result

# output to CSV
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\QueryResultCondensed.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output for the example item:

> ```
> ID                  : 1584
> ObjId               : 
> ARTIKEL_NR          : 0
> ArtBeschrieb1_3     : 
> KLASSE              : TbXAusführungen
> SMB1                : TbA
> SMB2                : 2M-Zarge Front
> SMB3                : B;C-M;D-M
> SMB4                : 2.000000
> SMB5                : 
> SMB6                : 
> SMB7                : 
> SMB8                : 
> SMB9                : 
> SMB10               : 
> SMB11               : 
> SMB12               : 
> SMB13               : 
> SMB14               : 
> SMB15               : 
> SMB16               : 
> SMB17               : 
> SMB18               : 
> SMB19               : 
> SMB20               : 
> SMB21               : 
> SMB22               : 
> SMB23               : 
> SMB24               : 
> SMB25               : 
> SMB26               : 
> SMB27               : 
> SMB28               : 
> SMB29               : 
> SMB30               : 
> DividendPreisEinhet : 0
> SMB31               : 
> ArtBeschrieb1_2FR   : 
> SMB32               : 
> OOPreisklasse       : 
> SMB33               : 
> SMB34               : 
> SMB35               : 
> SMB36               : 
> SMB37               : 
> SMB38               : 
> SMB39               : 
> SMB40               :
> ```

Comment: Sorry I did not explain it good enough. your code helped me a bit to achieve the answer though. see my answer - maybe you see something to improve

Comment: @SimonS I see, that is not what I thought the question was about, mainly because of _SMB* should become the Property Name and either SMW* or SMN* the PropertyValue, depending on which is NULL and which is not._. Your code looks just fine to me. Well done!